# Is "Motivate your answer" correct English?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Me and a friend were having an argument recently over "Motivate your answer". He said this:

> see it like this, motivate = force that drives you, okay? motivate your choices = arguments you considered that have driven you towards that choice

So it appears to be a more literal translation, like:

> Give reason to your answer.

Is this the case, or is just simply wrong?

Comment: "Motivate" is used with a special meaning in mathematics and related fields.  Does this apply here?

Comment: Sounds wrong to me (a native English speaker), despite the definition you gave. (As does "Me and a friend...")

Comment: Can you use it in a complete sentence where you think one thing and your friend he other? And explain what your friend thinks and what you think? Otherwise there's little to go on here other than simply giving what we think 'motivate your answer.' could mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would probably go for "***justify***" your answer with the meaning of "give reasons for your answer". However, the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary states that "motivate" has precisely this meaning in formal South African English, so perhaps it is the same elsewhere too.

Comment: You may also "substantiate" your decision.

Comment: It would be good to include 'OALD licenses a sense << '​motivate something' (South African English, formal): to give reasons for something that you have stated _Please motivate your answer to question 5_'

Answer (score 0):

"Motivate" in the sense of "providing reasons" does not appear in canonical dictionaries, e.g. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motivate
However, it is widely used in scientific contexts, as in https://books.google.de/books?id=MCJ69lInYFEC&pg=PT224&lpg=PT224&dq=%22motivate+this+argument%22+linguistics&source=bl&ots=_juRyy9RO6&sig=ACfU3U0AvzIGX03g9etpLcg-MD6QyMbMpA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivpPjqgeboAhXJzKQKHVMrANMQ6AEwAHoECAoQLA#v=onepage&q=%22motivate%20this%20argument%22%20linguistics&f=false

Comment: Couldn't that be 'get it going'?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth What do you mean?

Comment: "I am going to motivate this argument ...."

Comment: Well, what about this one (Lyons)? https://books.google.de/books?id=yKDa40KtY8EC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=john+lyons+linguistics+%22motivate%22&source=bl&ots=4KgG58L3X6&sig=ACfU3U3_lFx_t1Mpien89wVaPeglL2O8kw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN-62WkeboAhWNX8AKHVu5CjgQ6AEwA3oECAsQPg#v=onepage&q=john%20lyons%20linguistics%20%22motivate%22&f=false   "Motivate" is widely used in the sense of "providing arguments" in scientific discourse.

Comment: Well, what about it? It looks good to me. Wouldn't it have been better to replace the less convincing evidence in your answer? // Note that, as Paola has said, OALD licenses a sense <<  '​motivate something' (South African English, formal): to give reasons for something that you have stated
_Please motivate your answer to question 5_ >>. But this is 'justifying arguments already / about to be presented', not 'suggesting arguments' / 'putting forward ideas'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In scientific discourse you can also use the term to justify a thesis you have started with. This is the field I am familiar with. I am not talking about conversational language. By the way, why "less convincing"?

Comment: It can be read in the 'get it going' sense; it's not necessarily the justify' sense there. So not a proof of usage. A cough and a temperature could be interpreted ....